# FindBy ManyToMany

Tags: symfony-3.4, findby

According to this link https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-objects.html in two entities related to ManyToMany, a search can be made by referring to the second entity.
This is my example:

```
UsuariosBundle\Entity\Users:
type: entity
table: null
repositoryClass: UsuariosBundle\Repository\UsersRepository
manyToMany:
    espec:
        targetEntity: UsuariosBundle\Entity\Especialidad
        inversedBy: users
        joinTable:
            name: fos_user_espec
            joinColumns:
                user_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            inverseJoinColumns:
                espc_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
    grupos:
        targetEntity: UsuariosBundle\Entity\Grupo
        joinTable:
            name: fos_user_grupo
            joinColumns:
                user_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            inverseJoinColumns:
                group_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
oneToMany:
    soli:
        targetEntity: SolicitudeBundle\Entity\Solicitudes
        mappedBy: user_creador
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
fields:
    name:
        type: string
        length: 50
    last_name:
        type: string
        length: 100
    foto:
        type: string
        length: 100
        nullable: TRUE
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }


UsuariosBundle\Entity\Grupo:
type: entity
table: null
repositoryClass: UsuariosBundle\Repository\RolesRepository
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
fields:
    name:
        type: string
        length: 50



$grupo = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository(Users::class)
    ->findByGrupos(1);
```

error:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'fos_user_grupo.group_id' in 'where clause'
Thanks!